typeorm TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
I use typeorm and awesome-cordova-plugins/sqlite/ngx for create and manage sqlite database, I have this error
enter image description here
code:
  public initDatasIfDBEmpty(datas: any): Promise<any> {
  return this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    createConnection({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: this.dbName,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: true,
      entities: [
        User
      ],
    }).then((connection: DataSource) => {
      console.log('connection');
      console.log(connection);
       connection.synchronize().then(() => {
  
            console.log('here.');
           
        }).catch((error: any)=>{
          console.log('error',error);
        });
      });
    });

  });

}

